# Crystal report missing parameter values when export

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

When I ran my crystal report, I run into an error where its shows missing parameter values

Below is my code

```
_crAdviceRpt.Load("C:\Users\whatever\AD_AdviceTemplate.rpt")

 Dim ds As ADDataset = New ADDataset
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables.Add("ADDatatable")
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("strLinesList", Type.GetType("System.String")))

    Dim dr As DataRow
    dr = dt.NewRow
    dr("strLinesList") = strLine
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    _crAdviceRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(1))

    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "location.pdf"
    CrExportOptions = _crAdviceRpt.ExportOptions
    With CrExportOptions
        .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
        .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
        .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
        .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
    End With
    _crAdviceRpt.Export()

    If Not _crAdviceRpt Is Nothing Then
        _crAdviceRpt.Close()
        _crAdviceRpt.Dispose()
        _crAdviceRpt = Nothing
    End If
```

In my dataset, it does like this:
ADDDataset.xsd-> ADDatatable -> strLinesList 
strLinesList is my column over here

In crystal report designer, I drag the strLinesList over to my .rpt

I'm not sure what is wrong but I'm pretty sure that something is missing in my code, so anyhere is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The Solution for this is to reorder the Crystal Parameters to match the Query Prompts

1) Open the problem report in Crystal Designer 
2) Right click the Parameters section and select reorder parameters 
3) Set the Parameter order to match that of the Prompts in the query 
4) save the report and retest

The Verify Database command on the Database menu checks the alias pointers stored in a report file to verify that the database files expected are located in the indicated directories. If the databases are not found in the specified location, the program notifies you of the discrepancies.

Using the Verify Database process

When you choose Verify Database from the Database menu, the program checks the active databases and reports. If it detects changes, the report must be adapted to prevent errors. The program displays the Map Fields dialog box when it detects either of these types of changes to the database: 
- The name of a database field that is used in the report has changed 
- The database has been upsized from a PC data source to an SQL data source.

Crystal Reports automatically adapts the report (and does not display the Map Fields dialog box) if it detects any of these changes: 
- Fields have been added to the database 
- Fields that are not used in the report have been deleted from the database 
- Field positions have changed in the database 
- Data types have changed for fields in the database.

Using the Verify on Every Print process

Verify on Every Print triggers the Verify Database command every time you print your report. 
- If there is a check mark beside Verify on Every Print, the option is active. It triggers Verify Database every time you print. 
- If there is no check mark beside it, the option is inactive. The option is inactive by default.

[Link](http://peoplesoft.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/peopletools-l/crystal-runtime-exception-missing-parameter-values-5158982)